Error in ku_format_slice(key$row, nrow) : Index is out of bounds for axis with size 10
I am trying to estimate interaction matrices in a loop. The first iteration should have the first 2 ids, the next the first 3 ids and so on until the last iteration is the entire dataset. However, I run into this error.

Error in ku_format_slice(key$row, nrow) :
Index is out of bounds for axis with size 10

library(recoverNetwork)

main_data <-  gendata(setting=15,1) #gendata is a function from the recover network package
main_data <- main_data[main_data$id <=7] 

unique_ids <- unique(main_data$id)
results <- list()  

# Loop over increasing number of IDs (cities)
for (i in 2:length(unique_ids)) {
  
  # Subset the IDs for the current iteration
  selected_ids <- unique_ids[1:i]  # Take the first i IDs
  
  # Filter the main data based on the selected cities
  data <- main_data[main_data$id %in% selected_ids, c("id", "time", "y", "x1") ]
  
  # Run the recoverNetwork function on the subset data
  rn <- recoverNetwork(data, lambda = c(0.10, 0.10, 0.10))
  
  # Extract the result
 W_matrix <- rn$unpenalisedgmm$W
  

  results[[i]] <-  W_matrix
  print(paste0("Done i=",i))
}

